# HTML layout for a div

Tags: html, css

How can I produce a div that will have the following layout so I could make its contents to adjust when is resized? How should i structure this, so I could make use of media queries? Do I need to have another div that will wrap all of this?

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------+
+           + Title                                 +
+Image      + Description                           +
+           +                                       +
+-----------+---------------------------------------+
+Another container                                  +
+                                                   +
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Update: 
Used both answers and came up with
http://jsfiddle.net/EzV4R/10/

Comment: how do you want its content to adjust? proportionately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the most of CSS3 and do away with inline styles (bad) and floats, try:

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cUW7/)

It has the added benefits of:

1. Resizing with the page
2. Minimizing the cell containing the image to only the image size (width)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>Image</div>
    <div class='cell'>Title<br />Description</div>
    <div class='caption'>Another container </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.cell :first-child{
    width:1%;
}
.caption {
    display:table-caption;
    caption-side:bottom;
}
.cell, .caption {
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

Comment: Are we now using <div> elements to create tables? It's like 10 years ago where we used <table> elements to create layouts, just in reverse! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I always like to wrap structures but it is not necessary, so I would try this:

HTML

```
    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
      <div id="topleft" class="left"></div>
      <div id="topright" class="right"></div>
      <div style = "clear:both">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #main {size that you want}
    #topleft {size that you want}
    #topright {size that you want}
    .left { float: left; }
    .right { float: right; }
    #container { width: 100% }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="topleft" style="float:left">TOPLEFT</div>
<div id="topright" style="float:right">TOPRIGHT</div>
<div id="container" style="clear:both">CONTAINER</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <div >
    <div  style="float:left width:50%">Image</div>
    <div  style="float:right width:50%">
    <div >Title</div>
    <div >Description </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div  style=" width:100%">Another container </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
  <div id="clr"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#main {margin:0;padding:0;}
#logo {width:20%;float:left;}
#desc {width:80%;float:left;}
#clr{width:100%;clear:both;}
#content{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
    <div class="inlineImg">
        <!-- image -->
    </div>
    <aside>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description</p>
    </aside>
</section>
<section id="other">Another Container</section>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
}

div.inlineImg {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

aside {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

#other {
    height: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWnXm/3/)